# How does PROJEN help standardize project config across infra/application projects

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, typescript-eslint

I have been playing with PROJEN and AWS CDK and finding hard to understand how does PROJEN help in standardizing project configs when you have multiple projects/repos. I can understand for a single project/repo it does the job with the help of the projen.js.

How does PROJEN act like a source of truth for all dependencies and config across projects for my organization? or How do we ensure all project teams/repos are using the same projen.js I have defined for one project? Do I need to copy and paste the same projen.js across all projects ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example of how we're using it and hopefully that will help.

We have a kubernetes platform and have multiple microservices that are all independently built and deployed across various teams. Each time writes their own code at their own pace but all need to have a common pattern for testing and deploying their microservices to the cluster.

We have a projen construct which represents a 'microservice' project. In that construct we have defined a GitHub Actions pipeline file, which will build and deploy to a testing environment any branch. We have another GitHub Actions file that will build and deploy the 'main' (trunk) to another set of environments (staging and then prod). We have other GitHub files like PR template and Issue templates, all defined as separate projen constructs that are included in the 'microservice' construct. There are some dials and project-specific settings that can be controlled at the project construct.

Additionally, there is a Dockerfile construct which stubs out (but does not own) the Dockerfile for the project to build.

I said before we have one projen construct? Actually we have three. One for JavaScript-based projects, one for typescript, and one for python. The JS/TS projects come with standard Eslint configuration files. The TS adds to that the ts compilation configuration files (tsconfig.json). The Python project sets up a requirements.txt file. Each projen project construct has language-specific settings but also the general GitHub Actions, GitHub PR/Issue templates, and etc.

All projects also include a standard LICENSE.md file and stub out a CONTRIBUTING.md file (which begins with just instructions on how the developers should maintain this file going forward.

If we decide later we need to change the way the pipeline works, we change that in one place, our 'microservice' projen construct and then we build and publish that new version. Notifications go out to all the teams that a new version (with new features) has been published and they install that new version and then run `npx projen` to get the new features applied to their repo. We just added in a new feature to the project that does PR title linting and label checking (all projects require a set of specific labels indicating they've been QA'd and are ready to merge).

When starting a new repo we just initialize it with the --from argument (https://github.com/projen/projen#projects-in-external-modules) and we have a repository ready for developers to begin working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please share the way to create and clone the 'microservice' projen construct to other projects? Currently as the original question, I just use `projen new`

Answer (score 0):

You would create a base `projen` configuration, then make it available for target projects, e.g. as a package published to a shared NPM registry.

When you make changes to the base configuration, you would go to the target repositories, update the package, make any necessary updates, e.g. for breaking changes, re-apply the changes and push a pull request.

In a sense, it's not much of a different workflow as you're already accustomed with for, say, having a shared ESLint configuration package.